# Is it possible to use .svg files with React Native without converting them?

Tags: react-native, svg

I have found many answers about converting .svg files to rasterized formats, however I would prefer to keep it as a single svg file. I got excited when I found `react-native-svg`, but was then disappointed when I saw their image example used a .jpg file.

Is keeping my image as a vector possible? Am I trying to do something unwise?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your SVG's to use the react-native-svg library, this is a useful tool to do so: https://react-svgr.com/playground/

This does not rasterise the image, it will remain as a vector just in a format that the library can parse.